# SqlBulkCopy - The given ColumnName does not match up with any column in the source or destination

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlbulkcopy

I'm trying to use SqlBulkCopy to copy data into an SQL database table however it is (wrongly) saying that the columns don't match. They do match. If I use a breakpoint to see the names of the columns being mapped, they're correct. The error message shows the name of the column, and it is correct.

This is my method. I have an identical method that *does* work and the only difference is where it gets the column names from. The strings containing the column names, however, are EXACTLY identical.

```
    public static bool ManualMapImport(DataTable dataTable, string table)
    {
        if(dataTable != null)
        {
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            SqlBulkCopy import = new SqlBulkCopy(connection);
            import.DestinationTableName = "[" + table + "]";
            foreach (string s in Global.SelectedColumns)
            {                    
            /* The s string variable here is the EXACT same as
               the c.ToString() in the other method below */

                if (ColumnExists(table, s))
                    import.ColumnMappings.Add(s, s); 
                else
                    return false;
            }

            connection.Open();
            import.WriteToServer(dataTable); //Error happens on this line
            connection.Close();

            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

This is the almost identical, working method:

```
    public static bool AutoMapImport(DataTable dataTable, string table)
    {
        if (dataTable != null)
        {
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            SqlBulkCopy import = new SqlBulkCopy(connection);
            import.DestinationTableName = "[" + table + "]";           
            foreach (DataColumn c in dataTable.Columns)
            {
                if (ColumnExists(table, c.ToString()))
                    import.ColumnMappings.Add(c.ToString(), c.ToString());
                else
                    return false;
            }

            connection.Open();
            import.WriteToServer(dataTable);
            connection.Close();

            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

If it helps, the column names are: ACT_Code, ACT_Paid, ACT_Name, ACT_Terminal_Code, ACT_TCustom1, ACT_TCustom2. These are exactly the same in the database itself. I'm aware that SqlBulkCopy mappings are case sensitive, and the column names are indeed correct.

This is the error message:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: The given ColumnName 'ACT_Code' does not match
>   up with any column in data source.

Hopefully I'm just missing something obvious here, but I am well and truly lost.

Many thanks.

> EDIT: For anyone happening to have the same problem as me, here's how
>   I fixed it.
>
> Instead of having the `ManualMapImport()` method be a near-clone of
>   `AutoMapImport()`, I had it loop through the columns of the datatable
>   and change the names, then called `AutoMapImport()` with the amended
>   datatable, eliminating the need to try and map with plain strings at
>   all.

Comment: What is `Global.SelectedColumns` and where is it coming from/how is it populated?  I thought it was the `SelectedColumns` property from `DataGridView`, but that doesn't return strings.

Comment: It's just a `List<string>` filled with column names. It's populated by querying the database for a list of columns in a chosen table and putting it into a `Global.AllColumns` list, then the user is able to select which ones they want in which order in correspondance to a CSV file that they will open with the application. The chosen columns are copied into `Global.SelectedColumns`

Comment: Is that the *exact* message?  It doesn't look like what I remember..?

Comment: Also, what version of SQL server?

Comment: That is the exact message, copied and pasted. It is 2014 express, but this application will be used with various versions.

Answer (score 4):

According to MSDN ([here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.tostring(v=vs.110).aspx)), the `DataColumn.ToString()` method returns "*The Expression value, if the property is set; otherwise, the ColumnName property.*".

I've always found the `ToString()` method to be wonky anyway (can change based on current state/conditions), so I'd recommend using the `ColumnName` property instead, as that's what you are actually trying to get out of `ToString()`.

---

OK, failing that, then I'd have to guess that this is a problem with case-sensitivity in the names of the columns in the source datatable, as `SQLBulkCopy` is *very* case-sensitive even if the SQL DB is not.  To address this, I would say that when you check to see if that column exists, then you should return/use the actual string from the datatable's column list itself, rather than using whatever string was passed in.  This should be able to fix up any case or accent differences that your ColumnsExist routine might be ignoring.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll change that, however I'm certain .ToString() isn't the issue here. It's the top method that doesn't use .ToString() that isn't working. The DataColumn.ToString() is working.

Comment: It's not that either unfortunately. I already am taking them straight from SQL and populating my lists with them.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem... The message might seem a bit misleading, as it suggests you didn't perform the correct mapping.

To find the root of the problem I have decided to go step by step in adding table columns and calling the `WriteToServer` method.

Assuming you have a valid column mapping, you will have to ensure the following between the source `DataTable` and the destination table:

- The column types and lengths (!) do match
- You have provided a valid value for each non-empty (`NOT NULL`) destination column

If you don't control your identity column values and would like the SQL Server do this job for you, please make sure **not to** specify the `SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity` option. In this case you don't add the identity column to your source either.

This should be all for your bulk insert to work. Hope it helps.

Comment: To illustrate this with an example... my insert was failing because in the source for a column [A] I had a value of "ABCD", while the mapped column [A] in the destination table was char(2).