# Column Name does not match with any column in datasource

Tags: c#, .net

I have below data table :-

[image]

I have below SQL table as `Product`:

[image]

ITEM CODE from data table is `ProductCode` in SQL.

CLOSING (Last column in image) from data table is `Quantity` in SQL.

I wanted to update ITEM CODE against CLOSING (Quantity) in SQL.

I wrote this bulk update function:

```
using (SqlBulkCopy bcSQL = new SqlBulkCopy(con))
{
    bcSQL.DestinationTableName = "Product";

    // Map Source column name to Destination Column name
    // Src Column is in your DataTable
    // Dest Column is column name available in your SQL Table
    bcSQL.ColumnMappings.Add(" ITEM CODE", "ProductCode");
    bcSQL.ColumnMappings.Add(" Closing", "Quantity");

    bcSQL.WriteToServer(dt);
}
```

But I get this error:

> The given ColumnName ' ITEM CODE' does not match up with any column in data source.

Please help - how can I resolve this?

Comment: Wild guessing because I am not working with SqlBulkCopy but try not using spaces ' ' when naming columns. I know in past it was making problems to me. Use `_` instead and try code again. Again this is wild guess but until someone else come you have something to try.

Comment: Can you check the column names in the dt  and see if they are the same as you see them in the first image?

Comment: Even if the message is about column names, the problem might be in the data. Check the data tpes and lengths match. Check also the default values when data is NULL. Finally, check that you don't have an identity key in those columns. Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46561241/1182515).

Comment: Also, unrelated, but probably you should use uppercase for the `" CLOSING"` mapping.

Comment: Thanks Both Of You spacing was the issue

Answer (score 0):

Since I was filling data table from Excel , I didnt noticed spaces in column names.

There were 2 blank spaces after column names

When I modified it like :-

```
bcSQL.ColumnMappings.Add("ITEM CODE  ", "ProductCode"); //2 spaces
```

It got resolved.

Key Issue :- Column names as mentioned in comment section